# Intermittent Failure with Blackjack code

Tags: c

The purpose of this code is to play a simulated game of Blackjack. The 'Dealer' is automated and will deal two cards to itself and stop when it wins/busts or hits 17. Then the user draws until he/she is satisfied. Then a winner is determined.

I've run into a brick wall because the code compiles fine, but when it runs it will either work (and by work I mean not work as intended but it will run) or it will crash.

I have no idea how this can happen only some of the time and not all of the time and I need some help.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 52
#define LIMIT 21 

enum faces{Ace = 0, Jack = 10, Queen, King};
char * facecheck(int d); 
void shuffle( int deck[]);
int draw(int deck[SIZE]); 
void printcards(int hand[], int numCards);
int dealer(int deck[]);  
int player(int deck[]);
int value(int yourhand[]); 
int victory(int d, int p);
int i, numCards = 1;
int top = 52;
int preValue = 0; 
int count = 2; 
int main() 
{ 
    int deck[SIZE], i, a;
    int d, p; 
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};


    srand( time( NULL ) ) ;

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = i;
    };

    shuffle(deck);
    d = dealer(deck);
    p = player(deck);
    victory(d, p);



    return 0; 
}  

char * facecheck(int d)
{
    static char * face[] = 
    {
        "Ace",
        "Jack",
        "Queen",
        "King" };

    if(d == Ace)
        return face[0];
    else
    {
        if(d == Jack) 
            return face[1];
        else
        {
            if(d == Queen)
                return face[2];
            else 
            { 
                if(d == King)
                    return face[3];
            }
        }
    }
}



void shuffle( int deck[]) 
{
     int i, j, temp; 

     for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
           j = rand() % SIZE; 
           temp = deck[i];
           deck[i] = deck[j];
           deck[j] = temp;
           }
     printf("The deck has been shuffled \n"); 
} 

int draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
    int numCards = 1;
    int i;  
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++)
    {
        card = deck[top-1];     
        hand[i] = card; 
        top--;   
    }

    return card;

}

void printcards(int hand[], int numCard)
{   
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};

    for(i = 0; i < numCard; i++) 
    {
     int card = hand[i];     
    if(card%13 == 0 || card%13 == 10 || card%13 == 11 || card%13 == 12)
        printf("%s ", facecheck(card%13) );
    else 
        printf("%d ", card%13+1);
    printf("of %s \n", suits[card/13]);
    }
}

int dealer(int deck[])
{
    int x;
    int a; 
    int yourhand[10];
    int handIndex = 0;
    int cardLimit;
    int dealerValue;

        yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
        yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
        printf("The Dealers second card is:"); 
        printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);

        cardLimit = value(yourhand);

        do
        {
         if(cardLimit == LIMIT)
         {
             printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
             dealerValue = cardLimit;
             return dealerValue;
         }

         if(cardLimit > LIMIT)
         {
             printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
             dealerValue = cardLimit;
             return dealerValue;
         }
         if(cardLimit == 17)
         {
             printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
             dealerValue = cardLimit;
             return dealerValue;
         }
         if(cardLimit <= 16)
         {
            yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
            cardLimit = value(yourhand);
         }
        }
         while(cardLimit <= LIMIT); 
         handIndex++;


}

int player(int deck[])
{
    int x;
    int a; 
    int yourhand[10];
    int cardLimit;
    int playerValue;
    int handIndex = 2;

    yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
    yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
    cardLimit = value(yourhand);
    printf("Your hand is: /n"); 
    printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
    printf("%d /n" , cardLimit); 

    do
        {
         if(cardLimit == LIMIT)
         {
             printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
             playerValue = cardLimit;
             return playerValue;
         }

         if(cardLimit > LIMIT)
         {
             printcards(yourhand, handIndex+1);
             playerValue = cardLimit;
             return playerValue;
         }
         else
         {
             printf("What would you like to do: Press 1 to Hit. 2 to Stay. \n"); 
             scanf("%d" , &x);
             if(x == 1)
         {
            yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
            cardLimit == value(yourhand);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Player choses to stay \n");
                return playerValue;
            }
        }
        }
        while(cardLimit <= LIMIT); 

        handIndex++;
}

int value(int yourhand[])
{
    int faceValue = 10;
    int cardValue[count]; 
    int aceValue = 11;
    int card[count]; 
    int value; 
    int curvalue; 


      for(i = 0; i < count; i++) 
      {
      card[i] = yourhand[i];
      }

     for(i = 0; i < count; i++) 
     { 
         cardValue[i] = card[i]%13; 
     } 

     if(cardValue[0] >= 10 && cardValue[1] >= 10)
     {
         value = 20;
     }
     if(cardValue[0] < 10 && cardValue[1] < 10) 
     {
         value = cardValue[0] + cardValue[1];
     }
     if(cardValue[0] >= 10 && cardValue[1] < 10) 
     {
         value = faceValue + cardValue[1];
     }
     if(cardValue[0] < 10 && cardValue[1] >= 10) 
     {
         value = faceValue + cardValue[0];
     }
     if(cardValue[0] == 0 && cardValue[1] == 0) 
     {
         value = 12; 
     }       
     if(cardValue[0] == 0 && cardValue[1] >= 10) 
     {
         value = 21;
     }
     if(cardValue[1] == 0 && cardValue[0] >= 10) 
     {
         value = 21;
     }        
     if(cardValue[0] == 0 && cardValue[1] < 10) 
     {
         value = aceValue + cardValue[1];
     } 
     if(cardValue[1] == 0 && cardValue[0] < 10) 
     {
         value = aceValue + cardValue[0];
     } 

     preValue = value;

     if(count > 2) 
     { 
        if(cardValue[count] != 0) 
        {
               value = curvalue; 
               value = preValue + curvalue;
        }   
        else
        {
            if(cardValue[count] + preValue > LIMIT) 
            {
                 value = preValue + 1; 
            }
            else
            {
                value = cardValue[count] + aceValue;
            }
        }
     }
     count++; 
     return value; 
}

int victory(int d, int p)
{
    if(d > p) 
    printf("Dealer Wins \n"); 
    else
    printf("Player Wins"); 
}
```

Comment: You could try running it under http://valgrind.org/ which is a tool designed to detect things like memory corruption automatically.

Comment: At what point in the program do the crashes occur?

Comment: You need to learn to use the debugger available in whatever environment you are developing in to at least get the point in the program where you are crashing.  This will be your first clue; however, if the program is crashing because it is overwriting the heap or stack, the point of the crash may not be the point of the problem.  That's why C is hard :)

Comment: @user2368065 If you are compiling your program in release mode/with optimizations enabled, you will not be able to watch all variables, as C/C++ compilers aggressively optimize away as many variables as it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
int dealer(int deck[])
{
    int handIndex = 0;
    int yourhand[10];
    yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
    yourhand[handIndex] = draw(deck);
```

you never change `handIndex`, so these two assignments are to the same element (ie, the second  draw overwrites the first)

```
    cardLimit = value(yourhand);
```

now, having written to `yourhand[0]` twice, and without initialising any other elements, you  call `value` which expects `yourhand[0]` *and* `yourhand[1]` to be initialised.

This should be visible under valgrind (you're reading random values from uninitialized memory).

Comment: What should i do to fix it? I've tried expanding handIndex and it still crashes from time to time.

Comment: You should fix your logic. Why does `value` take an array argument, and then assume an unrelated non-const global represents its length? Keep these things together (as arguments, not globals). What other errors does valgrind give you? Fix them. Where are the other crashes? Look at them in your debugger.